# horizontal scroll change location winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on a windows mobile 6.0 project.
I want to change the horizantal auto scroll in windows form, I used

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,100);
```

but is not working.
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `AutoScroll` as `true`

```
ctrl.AutoScroll = true;//this is false in default 
ctrl.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,100);
```